# Pyspark Join table by next bigger timestamp

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to join two tables with each other in pyspark using python. The problem I face is that both tables do not have a primary key that I could use to match them on. But I know that they should match at the next bigger timestamp and an equal id. So assuimng the following:
Table 1:

| Timestamp1 | ID1 |
| --- | --- |
| 15:00:00 | 26 |
| 15:15:00 | 27 |
| 15:30:00 | 26 |

Table 2:

| Timestamp2 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 14:59:00 | 26 |
| 15:14:00 | 27 |
| 15:29:00 | 26 |

As a result I'd like to achieve something like this:

| Timestamp1 | ID1 | Timestamp2 | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15:00:00 | 26 | 14:59:00 | 26 |
| 15:15:00 | 27 | 15:14:00 | 27 |
| 15:30:00 | 26 | 15:29:00 | 26 |

My approach was something like this:
`final_df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df_1 INNER JOIN df_2 ON df_1.Timestamp1 > df_2.Timestamp2 and df_1.ID1 == df_2.ID2")`

But here of course there will be a match for every ID that is bigger than Timestamp2.. Is there an elegant way to only match with the closest bigger Timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

After the join you defined, you could use a Window-function to assign a rank to the duplicate lines and select the one with the lowest `timestamp_1`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window, function as F

final_df = (
    sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df_1 INNER JOIN df_2 ON df_1.Timestamp1 > df_2.Timestamp2 and df_1.ID1 == df_2.ID2")
    .withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('ID1').orderby('Timestamp1'))
    .where('rank == 1')
)
```